# unexpected crash when using custom fonts with swift

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, textkit

i am trying to determine the size of attributedString with method

```
func boundingRect(with size: CGSize, options: NSStringDrawingOptions = [], context: NSStringDrawingContext?) -> CGRect
```

and thats my code

```
paragraphRect = finalString.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width:textViewExample.frame.size.width - 10, height: CGFloat(CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)), options: ([.usesLineFragmentOrigin,.usesFontLeading]), context: nil)
```

but i get this exception

```
-[_SwiftValue renderingMode]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000050110
```

but when i use system fonts .. it works good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting answer so others don't get confused:

```
UIFont(name: UIFont.lightFontName(), size: 14)!
```

Answer (score 1):

**using custom font then the font should be unwrapped:**

```
UIFont(name: UIFont.lightFontName(), size: 14)!
```